# What does an Apple weather page consist of?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am currently developing an app which needs a page like the one in the apple weather(the default one for Apple device). The whole page can scroll vertically, for the hourly weather report part, it can scroll horizontally.

I wish I can demonstrate with a picture but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry about that.

Does the Apple weather page consists of one tableview with 3 cells (the hourly horizontal scrolling cell, the weather predictions for next 10 days cell, and the details for today cell) or it consists of  tableviews with 1 cell each?

Anyone has ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a `UIPageViewController`. You can put a usual `UIViewController` with an embedded `UIScrollView` inside it.

Comment: @HAS For the horizontal scroll part, can I make the elements in it programmable? I mean, can I put something like table cell in the scroll view instead of images.

Comment: Yeah, sure!  (i.e. you don't put table view cells into a scroll view, you use a tableview )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is one tableview with different cells. Horizontal scrollable part you can create with [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/). If you want float effect for this part, you need use it as UITableView section header. If you want this part was a usual part of the table, you need use it as UITableViewCell subview ([Example](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell)).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by using `UIPageViewController`, then use `UIViewController` for each page. You can find more about the basic principal of it [here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/).

Place your desired `UITableView` inside the intended `UIViewController` in the `UIPageViewController`.

Hope this helps. 
All the best.

Comment: I don't want to have several pages, I just want one single page which has those 3 parts. Thank you for the help.